# Is declaring an inner class in a View dangerous?

Tags: android, view, memory-leaks, inner-classes

I've read the official Android technical article: `"how to avoid memory leaks ?"`. They say that creating inner classes in an `Activity` class is dangerous, but what about creating inner class inside a `View` class : is the leak danger the same or worse ?

Comment: I would imagine the "danger" of such an inner class is that all instances of such a class are implicitly bound to the containing class: thus leaking this object could keep the "parent" class from being reclaimable (in a timely manner). Remember, [an *inner class* is a specific sub-set of a *nested class*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html).

Comment: Thank you, in fact i was in trouble that the Android activities are sensible contexts, as described in the technical article. So I wondered whether the Android Views are sensible too. But thanks to Jin35, now I know that it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create classes with lifecycle not more than view - it's OK. Otherwise you should avoid doing this.

If you use such structure - be sure, that you do not have any links on instances of inner class, when view is not necessary. Then GC will collect everything, and there will not memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I need the inner class in order to programm a short animation on my custom View. The animation class just call some methods of the outer View class. And I won't keep any reference to the newly created inner class instance.